# Django OAuth Toolkit with Multiple Grants

Tags: django, oauth

I'm using Django OAuth Toolkit and I would like to register applications with multiple grants. Some applications may have just one type of grant, others may have more.

The official documentation:

http://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_topics.html#multiple-grants

recommends:

```
class MyApplication(AbstractApplication):
def allows_grant_type(self, *grant_types):
    # Assume, for this example, that self.authorization_grant_type is set to self.GRANT_AUTHORIZATION_CODE
    return bool( set(self.authorization_grant_type, self.GRANT_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS) & grant_types )
```

but I get an error saying that "TypeError: set expected at most 1 arguments, got 2"

Also as I understand this doesn't modify the model in the db. This would return if the intersection of the sets is empty or not. So won't this make (if it works) the GRANT_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS available to *all* applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like the error says 
the set function expect one parameters you gave it 2
so you need to modify your code a little bit like that

```
    return bool( set([self.authorization_grant_type, self.GRANT_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS]) & set(grant_types) )
```